# teechart 2020 trial version install package missing entry point

Tags: delphi, installation, teechart

I've just installed the trial version of Steema TeeChart Pro 2020 VCL/FMX for RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo into my Win10 dev VM.  The installation went normally - it raised the issue of the missing GDI HPP files, which I downloaded and installed before continuing - and the install reported that it completed without errors.  However, when I start the IDE or when trying to enable the package from within the IDE, I get a missing-entry-point error for `@System@Net@HttpClient@Win@TWinHttpLib@$bcctr$qqrv` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steema Software\Steema TeeChart Pro VCL FMX 2020.29\Delphi25\Delphi25.win32\Bin\DclTeePro925.bpl`.  I've cleared any other potential conflicting packages.  Anyone else experienced this? Any ideas on clearing it?

Comment: Contact Steema directly for support for their trial product.

Comment: OK. Their website seemed to indicate that support could be found here as well.

Comment: @SteveS and it should.  I had issues with new TeeChart Pro and was unable to resolve.. I ended up using TMS Advanced Charts, worth a look.

Comment: @John Easley, thanks - what problems did you have?  I was installing it for the gauge controls, as my boss loved the look they offered and wanted me to try them as a possible replacement for the older IOComp gauge controls we've been using... but if they're problematic, I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: @SteveS  what version of Delphi are you using?  Make sure that the TeeChart version you are installing supports the version you are using. Let me know.

Comment: @John Easley see my answer - versioning (specifically hotfixes) was the answer.  I use TMS for a lot of stuff, but their instrumentation lib is pretty dated, especially in the Ux area.  I'm doing industrial automation, and our customers are finally starting to want a Ux that looks like their phone rather than one from 10 years ago. :)

Comment: @SteveS I found the same post in the Steema forum, that's why I asked about Delphi version :)

Answer (score 1):

After further searching, I found a link to the Steema forum where this issue is discussed. 
The answer to this is indeed one of versioning.  I was running 10.2.2 but not the last hotfix; the hotfix addresses a bug in the RTL's HTTP support, which was causing the load issue.

I've updated to 10.2.3, which clears the Steema problem, but be aware that the upgrade requires a full uninstall of the earlier version, so you'll need to save all your environment config, uninstall 10.2.x, install the 10.2.3 version (6Gb download) and re-install any GetIt or other 3rd-party packages.